# how can I communicate between instances of openstack

Tags: openstack

I have created few instances on openstack,is it possible to  communicate between them using ip addresses directly using ssh or any configuration steps are required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends. If installation of Openstack components, bridges, configurations are correct pinging between VMs is a simple thing to do. If not check the following:

1. Make sure VMs got IP addresses
2. If VMs are not getting IP, check DORA packets are observed going out of compute node and received at network node. On network node check for DHCP namespace of the VM's network.
3. In security group rules allow icmp and ssh.
4. Identify the compute node and respective switches to which these VMs are attached to.
5. Do iptables -L and make sure icmp/ssh traffic is not blocked.

This is not a comprehensive checklist but should give some idea why traffic is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Actually communicating between instances you created is based on what network topology you are using.

Suppose you create these instances in the same network.

Firstly you should make sure you have add security group to these instances which allows 22, used by ssh.

Secondly you should make sure the image you used to allows ssh by using ssh-key or root-password.

Thirdly you could try this command `nova-console $instane_id` to see if your default password is showed or you know the password. You could try to ssh into one of these instances and try to `telnet ip 22` another.

If there is something wrong, you should try to define your network resources to make sure they are correct.

Hope this could help you .